# how to search through only unread emails and mark them read after

Tags: php

I have emails coming in with vehicle locations and I would like to record location in my database. I figured out how to fetch emails and find part of the content. Now I need to figure out how to search the content ONLY of not yet read emails and mark them read after I'm done.

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .     imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'FROM "onlyoneemail@email.com"');

if($emails) {
  $output = '';
  rsort($emails);
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);

    if (preg_match('/\bAddress\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*$/mi', $message, $match)){
        echo $match[1] . "<br>";
    }
  }
  echo $output;
} 

imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what the problem is with the code you have so far.

Comment: Current code searched through ALL emails in the email box. I need to search ONLY unread emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the keyword `UNSEEN` to the search criteria in your `imap_search()` like this:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM "onlyoneemail@email.com" UNSEEN');
```